# How to pass a tempfile as a command line parameter

Tags: go, temporary-files

I am trying to use a tempfile so that I can pass the tempfile as an argument to a exec command.

I declare the command I am going to use as

```
CLI_CMD := "/home/go/src/hello/abc.sh"

xmlFile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", hostIP)
command := CLI_CMD + " " + xmlFile.Name()
```

I finally run the command as

```
cmd := exec.Command(command)
stdout, err := cmd.Output()
```

To confirm abc.sh is present I do

```
[prompt] ls /home/go/src/hello/abc.sh
/home/go/src/hello/abc.sh
```

Also to confirm that the Tempfile is present , I do

```
[prompt] ls /tmp/10.166.30.47.xml187906126
/tmp/10.166.30.47.xml187906126
```

I can see both of these files being present here using the ls command. I am not getting why I am getting an error which fails to find either of these files. Also what file is not found here, the .sh file or the tempfile

```
2019/03/08 17:50:31 fork/exec /home/go/src/hello/abc.sh /tmp/10.166.30.47.xml187906126: no such file or directory
```

I have tried to summarize the code to make it easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your execution part like this.

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash","-c",command)
```